# What is the name of an excercise where the teacher reads some text and then students have to retell it in written form?

Tags: word-request

How in English speaking countries you name a kind of scholar work when the teacher reads some text a few times, and then students have to retell (in a written form) it as close to the original as they can?

Here we call it "изложение" but this word is also multi-meaning in Russian. The dictionary tells me "exposition, statement, narration, recital, recitation, presentment, relation." Which of them?

Basically, we have 3 kinds of big textual exercises:

1. Сочинение (essay?) - the teacher gives a theme and students have to write a few pages of text about it.
2. Изложение (recital?) - the teacher reads some text a few times and then students have to retell it close to the original
3. Диктант (dictation?) - the teacher slowly reads a text and students have to write following him. It is more about spelling and punctuation.

Comment: This is not a familiar kind of instruction to me, would the verb "transcribe" (https://www.dictionary.com/browse/transcribe?s=t) describe the action?

Comment: Sometimes called an **aural comprehension test**, or **listening comprehension**.

Comment: I would call it 'comprehension' too. It tests how well the students have _comprehended_ (understood) the meaning of the text.

Comment: @KateB - If students were expected to summarize and paraphrase the text, then I, too, would call it comprehension. If they are expected to write the text verbatim, though (which seems to be the case here), I don't think _comprehension_ is the right word. This question is not an easy one to answer, though, because this technique is not often used in classrooms. I can't recall ever being asked to do this as a student. Verbal recitation, sure – but not writing down something I've just heard verbatim.

Comment: @J.R. It might be a comprehension test as concerns its function or what the idea behind the test is, but that same term is applied to a test in which a student is asked to answer questions regarding a text, right? The closest (literal) method-aware term here is *retelling* or *recounting*. I don't know which of these would actually be used in an anglophone school, if they'd be used at all. Because *comprehension* is ambiguous, I'd say *the teacher told us to retell the text*, or *to summarize the text*, or *make a summary of the text*. I've never heard of this sort of exam either.

Comment: @JeffMorrow *Transcribe* and *transcription* are most often used to refer to writing down spoken language.  See e.g. [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/transcription) or the [LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/transcribe).

Comment: @snailcar I am going to delete my comment because you are correct with reference to popular usage. That popular usage is sloppy: there is a "record" of a judicial proceeding. A university transcript is not a record of a conversation. But I was allowing my preferences on how I use the language to slant what I said about popular usage. So you were right, and I was wrong. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your first context could be called one of several words depending on context, the most general being "essay," which means a piece of non-fiction on a single topic or a set of very closely related topics  (and usually means a relatively short work as well).

The second context, which is not a standard form of pedagogy in the U.S., is called a "paraphrase," which means a statement that reflects the meaning of another statement in different words.(Personal opinion: this should be a standard form of pedagogy: I used to have a boss who would say "Now tell me what I want you to think about." I picked up the trick. It was a very good way to make sure that there was mutual understanding.)

The third context, which also is not standard in U.S. pedagogy except in some old-fashioned teaching of languages other than English, cannot, as far as I know, be described by a single word or stock phrase. Back in a previous millennium, when I used to go to school on a sledge dragged by mammoths and studied French in a manner that was outdated even then, it was called a "dictee," which is French rather than English. The closest to your meaning is the word "dictation," which means the act of speaking to a computer or another person with the expectation that the computer or person will then render into legible text what was spoken word for word. But "dictation" as a technique for teaching a language is not a meaning known to me. If it is used in that technical sense, few outside the teaching profession are aware of it.

**EDIT**: I see that one of the suggestions in the comments to your question suggests "summary" as a possible word for your second type of exercise. That may or may not be true. A "summary" is expected to paraphrase only the most important points. You will have to clarify if all material points are to be paraphrased ("paraphrase") or only the most significant points are to be paraphrased ("summary"). In other words, a "summary" is one kind of "paraphrase." It is usually best to go with the word with the more restrictive meaning if it conveys the intended meaning. So, depending on what you mean, use either "summary" or "paraphrase."

Comment: a sledge or sled? Anyway, dictée is just dictation.

Comment: @Lambie Are you sure that "dictee" has the identical field of meaning in French as "dictation" has in English? Equating fields of meaning between languages is super tricky. And I meant "sledge;" a mere sled could not have borne the weight of all those children. It was a huge contraption, made from split tree trunks, which was why it took a **team** of mammoths to move it. When I got to high school, they invented wheels and replaced the sledge with bullock carts except, of course, when it snowed.

Comment: Well, Jeff, yes I do. The teacher dictates a text to see if you can spell. That is a dictation. I happen to have a university degree from a French university and speak French fluently. The purpose of these dictations in France is spelling. In English-speaking countries, we don't do those in school. However, the translation is correct. There is no other possible translation unless you want to say dictation of a text, text dictation.

Comment: Well your opinion is just a mere opinion no matter what your unauthenticated academic credentials may be.  Please give me multiple sources in each langue of the field of meaning of "dictee" and "dictation," and if you expect any deference to be given to your self-asserted expertise in French, please say how we can vailidate your certifification from a a relevent grande ecole. Otherwise, this is just blague.

Comment: Two can play at this game. But really, I would not be so aggressive. I have no reason to lie: https://www.larousse.com/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/dicter/25237?q=dict%c3%a9 
The :Larousse says: to read out **as dictation**. Same thing. The verb is dicter and there are even championships in France. Here is one for engineers. https://dictee.orthodidacte.com/ Here is a *dictée* (with an acute accent, by the way): for beginners. French dictation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWebPC9BlXw

Comment: And by the way, allow me to inform you that professional translators like myself know that there is no such thing as identical field of meaning. There is **equivalent meaning**.  Yes, if you knew my name, which I am not going to reveal, you could ask the ESIT at the Université de la Sorbonne Nouvelle (Paris III). You mean: this is just **une blague**. Oh, and by the way,  you might want to get the International Keyboard so you can easily type the accents in French and **other European languages**.

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/users/9299/lambie

Comment: You still have not shown that "dictation" has a meaning in English as a type of exercise for teaching a language. My whole point was that there is such a word in French and presumably in other languages. The field of meaning differs in that respect.

Comment: The discussion is not about **teaching *a* language**. It 's about **written French specifically** as written French has spelling issues that other languages do not. There are word endings that are not sounded. And I have given several sites that use the word dictation (une dictée) in the context of teaching **French**. You don't even speak French, do you? French students do them too. It is not just for teaching non-French speakers. The semantic field does not differ in teaching circles. The same semantic field.

Comment: The question is about what word in English corresponds to a method of teaching used in Russia. I pointed out that the method used to be used in teaching French in the U.S. but even then was named using a French word rather than an English one. I also said that if "dictation" is used in the technical sense of a method of instruction, "few outside the teaching profession are aware of it." Rather than assuming, wrongly, that I cannot read French, it seems the real question is whether you can read English.

Comment: The French word is not used in English when referring to the method. The English word dictation is used. Look in any dictionary: they are the same semantic field for the meaning here. Le patron a dicté une lettre à sa sécretaire. The boss dictated a letter to his secretary. And dictée, dictation is in the authoritative Larousse Dictionary. On n'a pas eu de dictée en classe aujourd'hui. We didn't have a dictation during class today.

Answer (score 0):

- Essay writing [not always in class. It's often homework]
- Listening comprehension. The teacher reads a text and then asks questions about it.
- Dictation [for French,for example] // word spelling

In English-speaking countries, dictation of a text is not usually used to check spelling.

The teacher may dictate a list of words for students to spell in writing.

[I realize others have mentioned some of these. I am merely summarizing the ideas.]